# Freeze on Windows Phone 8 SDK install

Tags: windows-phone-8

Then trying to install Windows Phone 8 SDK I get a freeze on startup window like this:

[image]

And one of my CPU cores is loaded to 100%, the installer freezes. The install log have [this content](http://pastebin.com/wmPZN1JR) after it freezes.

Any hints? I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro x64 on Intel Core 2 Quad processor (no SLAT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation (thanks goes to Sysinternals Process Explorer), I've found that hang occurs in `wpfgfx_v0300.dll` module, which is, IIRC, a part of .NET Framework 3.0. So I went to "Programs and Components", then "Turn On/Off Windows Components" and turned off `.NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)` component. Reboot and voila, installer runs perfectly!